# Is there a way to use Class Template Argument Deduction Guide recursively? (is it Turing Complete)

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I am playing with Class Template Deduction Guide and trying to use it recursively. But I am not able to get the following code to compile

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
using int_const = std::integral_constant<int,N>;

template<int N>
struct Foo{
    constexpr static int value = N;

    template<int C>
    constexpr Foo(int_const<C>){};
};

Foo(int_const<0>) -> Foo<1>;

template<int N>
Foo(int_const<N>) -> Foo<N*(Foo{int_const<N-1>{}}.value)>;

int main(){
    return Foo{int_const<5>{}}.value;
}
```

This is the error:

> ```
> <source>: In substitution of 'template<int N> Foo(int_const<N>)-> Foo<(N * >     Foo{std::integral_constant<int, (N - 1)>{}}.value)> [with int N = -894]':
> <source>:17:51:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<int N> Foo(int_const<N>)-> Foo<(N * Foo{std::integral_constant<int, (N - 1)>{}}.value)> [with int N = 4]'
> <source>:17:51:   required by substitution of 'template<int N> Foo(int_const<N>)-> Foo<(N * Foo{std::integral_constant<int, (N - 1)>{}}.value)> [with int N = 5]'
> <source>:20:30:   required from here
> <source>:17:1: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
>  Foo(int_const<N>) -> Foo<N*(Foo{int_const<N-1>{}}.value)>;
>  ^~~
> ```

compilation terminated.

Comment: I've rollbacked your question. Please do not answer your question in the question itself. If you want, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a helper template:

```
template<int N>
struct foo_helper
{ static constexpr int value = N * Foo{int_const<N-1>{}}.value; };
template<>
struct foo_helper<0>
{ static constexpr int value = 1; };
```

With this (and only) deduction guide:

```
template<int C>
Foo(int_const<C>)
-> Foo<foo_helper<C>::value>
;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cffcf0fab7e2c3a5) with `Foo{int_const<5>{}}.value` correctly evaluated to 120.

**Why is so?**

Because with the following deduction guide

```
template<int N>
Foo(int_const<N>) -> Foo<N*(Foo{int_const<N-1>{}}.value)>;
```

when CTAD kicks in, all guides are considered; even if you provided a more specialized guide (`Foo<0>`), this recursive guide is explicitly specialized and `Foo{int_const<N-1>{}}` eventually gets specialized for `N=0`, hence the infinite recursion.

The introduction of an indirection layer, `foo_helper` breaks this infinite recursion: you can specialize a class, not a deduction guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code works but my original question was about recursion in the guide itself. Is it possible? I am not sure why this code not working neither:  #include <type_traits>

template<int N>
using int_const = std::integral_constant<int,N>;

template<int N>
struct Foo{
    constexpr static int value = N;

    template<int C>
    constexpr Foo(int_const<C>){};
};

template<int N>
Foo(int_const<N>) -> Foo<
    (N>0) ? (N*(Foo{int_const<N-1>{}}.value)):1>;

    int main(){
        return Foo{int_const<5>{}}.value;
    }

Comment: @Hui Actually, you didn't ask any question. But if you have asked: no that kind of recursion is not possible. You need an intermediate helper/trait.

Comment: hmm, why does my second version of the code not work?

Comment: Because `int_const<N-1>` is instanciated for `N==0`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int N>
using int_const = std::integral_constant<int,N>;

template<int N>
struct Foo{
    constexpr static int value = N;

    template<int C>
    constexpr Foo(int_const<C>){};
};

template<int N>
constexpr auto previous_foo(){
    if constexpr (N<=0){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return decltype(Foo{int_const<N-1>{}})::value;
    }
 }

template<int N>
Foo(int_const<N>) -> Foo<(N>0)?N*previous_foo<N>():1>;


int main(){
    return Foo{int_const<5>{}}.value;
}
```